# Create and add multiple map(objects) fields in document in React Native Firebase Firestore

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I am new to React Native, and I am trying to build an app.

The problem I am facing now, is creating map(objects) in documents of firebase firestore using firebase.firestore().... .add function.

I've managed to get simple string inputs to save(name, title and age - what user types in text input are successfully saved) but I didn't find a way to make it save to objects(named maps in firebase firestore) & also let user add infinite teammates input in frontend.

My goal is for the user to be able to input this:
Age, Name, Title(already solved) and Teammates

So the document in firebase should have (Age:Str, Name:Str, Title:Str, Teammates:NestedObject(map)>Teammate1(Object)>Name,Title

-- I attached pictures of UI, and database currentDoc, and neededDoc for better clarification

How should I go about it? Would love if you could help me. Thanks

Pics: UserUI: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsv9d.jpg

actual Firestore Doc: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nABYy.jpg

needed Firestore Doc: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPyDt.jpg

EDIT /// SOLVED Firebase Map/Object uploading issue. However I still couldn't find a way to add n inputs to object.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { View, Image, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { user } from '../redux/reducers/user';
require("firebase/firestore") ;
require("firebase/firebase-storage") ;

export default function Save(props, {navigation}) {

const [age, setAge] = useState("");
const [name, setName] = useState("");
const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
//   const [teammates, setTeammates] = useState("");

const savePostData = () => {
        firebase.firestore()
        .collection('posts')
        .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
        .collection("userPosts")
        .add({
        
            teammates:{},
            age,
            name,
            title,
            createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
        }).then((function () {
            props.navigation.popToTop()
        }))
}

return (
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
        
        <TextInput 
        placeholder = "Age"
        onChangeText = {(age) => setAge(age) }
        />
        <TextInput 
        placeholder = "Name"
        onChangeText = {(name) => setName(name) }
        />
        <TextInput 
        placeholder = "Title"
        onChangeText = {(title) => setTitle(title) }
        />
        
        


        <Button title="Post" onPress = {() => savePostData()} />
    </View>
)
}
```

Comment: What does the doc look like if you provide a non-empty object for teammates?

Comment: @DKidwell I added another textinput which onChangeText adds teammateName inside teammates object, but it doesn't save other data. It's something that I get very wrong but don't know what. [link](https://imgur.com/a/JpoHngG)

Comment: @DKidwell - I fixed the saving problem to map/objects in firestore, I was using the wrong useState. What I still don't know is how to be able to add dynamic inputs (only when users presses a button) and each input to push to the parent object of teammates